# On specific elements in $p$-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a non-abelian finite $p$-group, and $x$ is an element of $G$ with maximum possible order, say $p^n$. Then, is it true that $x^{p^{n-1}}$ should be in the center of $G$?

Comment: Hint: Consider the non-abelian group of order $27$ where all non-identity elements have order $3$.

Comment: That is to say every element is in the center?

Comment: Let me know whether this is correct:  If order of $x$ is $p^n$ then order of $x^p$ is $p^{n-1}$, order of $x^{p^2}$ is $p^{n-2}$, and so on, the order of $x^{p^{n-1}}$ will be $p$. Isn't it?

Comment: @Groups Yes the statement in your comment is correct. But the answer to the question you asked is no, and Tobias has described a counterexample of order $27$.

Comment: OK! Much part of above discussion is clear now. Then, the question can me modified as follows: **if $G$ is a $p$-group, $x\in G$ is of maximum order equal to $p^n\geq p^2$, then is it necessary that $x^{p^{n-1}}$ should be in $Z(G)$?** If this question is to be posted differently, then I will post, otherwise, I will modify the above posted question.

Comment: The answer is still no, Let $G = \langle x,y,z \mid x^{p^2}=y^{p^2}=z^{p^2}=1, [x,z]=[y,z]=1,  [x,y]=z \rangle$.

Comment: Thanks Derek, Hoang and Kildetoft. Everything is clear now.